# 9-dimensional data classification

Tags: python, classification, unsupervised-learning, confusion-matrix

I have a dataset with 9 columns and 20 million rows. I have now split the dataset into two parts using IQR.
One part is my inliers, the other part is my outliers.

I now want to build a categorizer with which I can categorize whether a new, unknown data point lies within my dataset or not. In other words, I want a statement about whether the new data point is valid or not usable for me. In the end, with using my two parts (outliers and previously randomly cut-off parts of the inliers) i want to check the functionality.

In the three-dimensional space I can imagine this very well and, for example, span a shell around my point cloud with Convex Hull and then evaluate whether the new point now lies within this shell or not.

However, I now have problems doing this with my 9-dimensional data.

Can I achieve this with Convex Hull, and if yes how? If not, what else can I try to accomplish this categorization in such high dimensions? It is important here that I am not allowed to use a supervised learning approach and i can't reduce the amount of dimensions, they are all important. The language I use is Python.

Comment: You have two 9-dimensional clusters of data points and the corresponding distributions. Have you tried classifying new data based on $L_1$/$L_2$ distance from the cluster means or based on an [appropriate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance) distance from the distribution means?

Comment: @farhanhubble No, I haven't tried that. I have a problem imagining this in 9 dimensions and I'm afraid that distances might possibly be a misleading approach in 9 dimensions. Also, from what distance do I then classify as an invalid data point? If you have experience, im happy to learn something new and you can show me but i need to understand first. :)

Comment: You need to understand the distribution and correlation of the columns first as @lpounng points out in their answer.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your data distribution and how you define 'outline' and 'inline' precisely.

Let's start simple with a few 2D cases.

1. Look at this [image of a 2D-donut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyaOqm.png). Is it possible that *any 2-combo* of your 9-D columns is distributed like this? If possible, imagine a new data point at (0,0) i.e. the empty space in middle. Do you consider it inline or out?
2. Look at this [2D point cloud](https://www.visiondummy.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/correlated_2d.png) and imagine a new data point at (-5,5). If you consider x and y axis separately, this point is clearly inline. Is it inline or out to your application?

The first thing is to **precisely define, in mathematical terms, how to decide the boundary between inline and outline**. After this, we can then proceed to generalize the low-dimension definition to a high-dimensional one.

There is a last catch: the [curse of dimensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality)(section 'Distance function'). This basically states that in high dimension and for some distance metrics, all point pairs have little difference in the distances, thus we cannot tell if any point is inline or out. Some popular distance metrics e.g. L2 (Euclidean) distance are affected, so watch out.